# Displaying shortcut in context menu created by a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension, I added some new context menu items that can also be triggered using shortcuts.
I want to display those shortcuts for easier discoverability like Firefox does in the  hamburger menu [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bluaz.jpg).

But I don't see what property I should add to my existing items to do this.

maybe some thing like this :

```
menu_01 = 
{
    id: "DoStuff",
    title: "Do stuff",
    contexts: ["tab"],
    shortcut: "crtl+y"
}
```

I suppose I could append the shortcut string to the title but that would be ugly.